# Update a column for many records

Tags: sqlite, sql-update

I have a table `MYTABLE`with columns `product`, `version` and `valid`(Boolean).

Lets say some records are like:

**Before**

```
product1 - 1 - 0
product1 - 2 - 0 
product1 - 3 - 1
```

What I want is to select the second record with the product1 and version 2 and update its valid column to 1, and then update all the others records with the same product and version their valid value to 0. So after the table would be like:

**After**

```
product1 - 1 - 0
product1 - 2 - 1 
product1 - 3 - 0
```

I tried

```
UPDATE MYTABLE
SET valid = EXISTS(
                    SELECT * FROM MYTABLE AS T2
                    WHERE T2.product = 'product1' AND T2.version=2)
```

and it changed all the records valid column to 0...

Answer (score 1):

You could try execute 2 UPDATES

```
UPDATE LABELS
SET valid = 1 where product='product1' AND version=2;

UPDATE LABELS
SET valid = 0 where product='product1' AND version!=2;
```